# Q: Failed to start Light Display Manager

Tags: lightdm, desktop-environments

I have made a stupid mistake on my machine.
I was removing `ssh-server` and I succeeded. Next I wanted to remove `ssh-client`. When I typed `apt-get purge ssh-client` I got a huge package for uninstalling and I accidently pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What a dumb move, now every thing got removed. Now any chance to install any desktop environments and reconfigure lightdm and I can't login to <kbd>crt</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>2-8</kbd>

```
https://ufile.io/lxbjy  > /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Ubuntu 16.04 x64 xface

Comment: Please try to make the question understandable. This is important to get a good answer.

Comment: sorry,My question is ubuntu stop on " Failed to start Light Display Manager " and keep counting the file /var/log/apt/history.log have all the pkg the i purge !